# How to display Name in your Layout dynamically?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am working on an Android App, which needs to have a friend list. I am communicating to Server, Server returns me a "Name", how do I display this Name in my Layout.

My xml code:

```
 <LinearLayout 
    android:gravity="top" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" > 
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My Friend List" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/add_more_friends" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: developer.android.com  learn to walk before running

Comment: What does your code look like? You cannot expect stackoverflow to teach you those basic, have you tried following some basic Android tutorials?

Comment: @Simon, theadam: I did follow the basic tutorial, however, I am trying to have an "Add Friend feature" in my App, just like we have for facebook, but I don't want to integrate facebook SDK. It would be very nice if you guys could help me.

Comment: If you followed the tutorials, why don't you have an id on your TextView so that you can reference it?  This is not a code writing or tutorial site.  Everything you need is on the developer site.

Comment: @Simon: I did what you had suggested, however, it works well only for one name. The moment I try to add the next name, the previous name disappears, and the present one appears. Could you please tell how to retain the previous name as well as display the present one. I searched on developer.android.com, but, couldn't find what I was looking for. Your help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a `TextView` somewhere in your layout then you find that `TextView` using `findViewById` then you use `setText` on that `TextView` passing your name.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am actually trying to implement Add Friend feature in my App. I'll select any name from my contact, the contact name would be send to server, server would store the details and return me the name, I am now required to add this name in my friend list, so that, whenever, I open my friend list, all the name that I have added, should be displayed.

Comment: This is working fine, but, only for one name, the moment I am trying to add a next name, the previous one disappears, and only the present one appears. Could you tell me how to retain the previous names too?

Comment: If there are many friends you would need a ListView. Use ArrayAdapter<String> to refer the names

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll just implement it and would ping you back in case I have more queries :P.